# Command for dropping a specific MySQL database

Tags: mysql, cmd, terminal

In phpmyadmin, we can drop a specific database from operation tab and by hitting "DROP THE DATABASE (DROP)". But I need to drop a specific database using command prompt or terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [mysqladmin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqladmin.html) like

```
mysqladmin -uroot -pyourpassword drop database_name
```

In this case User: root with password: yourpassword will delete database database_name

You will get a warning and have to verify it

Comment: You can also use the `--force` option to skip the warning.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

DROP DATABASE `database`;

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/drop-database.html

Comment: I did not downvote, but this works in the mysql client or in any other SQL interface, but not at a shell prompt.